# OneDrive does not stop syncing on metered connection any longer, what can I do?

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, sync, onedrive

I just discovered that OneDrive has wasted 1 GB of my monthly data volume for syncing via my hotspot, despite it was configured as a metered connection in the Windows 10 (1903) settings app. In past, I did not have this issue. How can I ensure OneDrive stops syncing while a metered connection is used?

Answer (score 1):

You not only need to set your connection as metered in Windows but also in OneDrive.

Ensure the following setting is enabled:

[image: onedrive settings screenshot]

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, this setting is enabled.